# View height incorrectly measured Android 5+

Tags: android, android-viewpager, expandablelistview, pagerslidingtabstrip, residemenu

I've created fragment that is shown by reside menu (https://github.com/SpecialCyCi/AndroidResideMenu) as content for some menu item. The problem is that on **Android 5+** height of ExpandableListView (green frame) is not measured correctly it cuts off bottom strip (approximately height) of system navigation buttons that are below. Looks like scroll frame is under those buttons and I can't scroll to show this part.

[image: Incorrectly measured ExpandableListView]

Now. After many tries I got the views to be almost correctly measured. 
I've added in onCreateView of my fragment:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
    view.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
}
```

ExpandableListView doesn't go under system buttons, but I have blank space on the top of view. Unfortunately this blank space stays there even if I switch menu item.

Can anyone share ideas what might be wrong?

[image: Blank space on the top]

Comment: For what possible reason this is downvoted, without providing comment?!

Comment: can u provide demo code for reside menu as expandable list view, i have posted this question also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37154021/reside-menu-as-expandable-listview?noredirect=1#comment61845159_37154021

Comment: @Shan I am using reside menu as normal list. Here expandable list only coexists with menu (on screenshots hidden)

Comment: okay thanks for the feedback .. :) can u suggest how to make expandable reside menu instead of normal list view

Answer (score 0):

> I have encountered this problem too. ([Android ResideMenu library, bottom of Fragment has Cropping issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28952210/android-residemenu-library-bottom-of-fragment-has-cropping-issue))
>   As you said View height
>   incorrectly measured on Lollipop devices. I found partial solution for
>   it. While I'm trying to give transparency to the native navigation
>   bar, I set **android:windowTranslucentNavigation** true in my values-v21
>   folder. Then View height started to calculate correctly, but color of
>   the navigation bar has changed.

```
<resources>
        <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
            <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar</item>

     <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>

        </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi there after around one week of work I found the perfect solution.

> Main Activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

{
etWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

((LinearLayout.LayoutParams)

mToolbar.getLayoutParams()).setMargins(0, getStatusBarHeight(this), 0, 0);

}

public static int getStatusBarHeight(Context context) {
    int result = 0;
    int resourceId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        result = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }
    return result;
}
```

> AndroidManifest activity add this line

```
<activity
            android:name=".activity.Main"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
             android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
             android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
               android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

> styleV21

```
<style name="myTheme" parent="FridayfairTheme.Base">
      <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
</style>
```