# Reside menu as expandable listView?

Tags: android, expandablelistview, residemenu

I am using the [this](https://github.com/SpecialCyCi/AndroidResideMenu) library for one of my project, this library works Reside menu to display for only simple menu, I want to modify this library for reside menu to display as expnadableList, can anyone suggest any idea to display the reside menu to display ExpnadableListView.

Comment: how many level of expendable list view

Comment: @NoumanShah  more than 5 levels

Comment: basically reside menu is linearlayout.....you do it with customiz....

Comment: @ExceptionLover can u suggest on this